# Make a UiViewController stay in portrait mode iOS6 VS iOS5

Tags: ios5, ios6

I'm building an app for iOS5 and iOS6. I have this UIViewController inside a UINavigationController and I want it to stay in portrait mode.

The code works for iOS5, but not in iOS6.

```
// iOS5 rotation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

// iOS6 rotation
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{

    return YES;


}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

What's the problem here??? On SO I've found lot's of similar questions, but generally the answers are not working for me.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I was not precise, but I need a SINGLE view controller (the homepage of my app) to stay in portrait mode **and not all the app**.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, A lot depends on with which controller is your UIViewController embedded in.

Eg, If its inside UINavigationController, then you might need to subclass that UINavigationController to override orientation methods like this.

subclassed UINavigationController (the top viewcontroller of the hierarchy will take control of the orientation.) needs to be set it as self.window.rootViewController.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
 {
     return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate;
 }
 - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
 {
     return self.topViewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations;
 }
```

From iOS 6, it is given that UINavigationController won't ask its UIVIewControllers for orientation support. Hence we would need to subclass it.

**MOREOVER**

Then, For UIViewControllers, in which you need only PORTRAIT mode, write these functions

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}
```

For UIViewControllers, which require LANDSCAPE too, change masking to All.

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown);
    //OR return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

Now, if you want to do some changes when Orientation changes, then use this function.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

}
```

**VERY IMPORTANT**

in AppDelegate, write this. THIS IS VERY IMP.

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
     return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll);
}
```

If you want to provide only Portrait mode for all your viewcontrollers, then apply the portait mask. i.e UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait

Otherwise, if you want that some UIViewControllers stay in Portrait while others support all orientations, then apply an ALL Mask. i.e UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll

Answer (score 0):

Try out this :

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    UIInterfaceOrientationMask orientationMask = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    return orientationMask;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{   
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

This should work in order to support the portrait mode only.