# programmatically setting orientation in viewdidload is not working

Tags: ios, screen-orientation, device-orientation

I have created an app for ipad in which the homescreen should be displayed only in portrait mode. So i have used the below code in viewdidload.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

but it is not working. I am using ios 7 with xcode 5. If i open my app from landscape mode it shouuld automatically turn to portrait mode. but i am getting like this:

[image]

but it should be like this:

[image]

can any one help me to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The above method is depricated and cannot be used now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationPortrait];
```

This method is deprecated. You cannot use this method anymore.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813644/1405008

Above link gives detail on how to provide portrait only mode for `UIViewController`.

If you pushed into `NavigationViewController` then try this.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16152506/1405008

Comment: i checked the link it is restricting the entire app to portrait mode. but i need to restrict only my homescreen to portrait mode.other screens should work in both mode.

Answer (score 2):

Following code is about to transform a navigationController view from Portrait to Landscape programmatically:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
self.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*(90)/180.0);
self.navigationController.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width);
[UIView commitAnimations];

self.view.frame = self.view.frame; //This is necessary
self.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES; 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated:NO];

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
}
```

Just hope to provide you some other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

copy this code in your viewdidload

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = (UIInterfaceOrientation)[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    isLandscapeMode = NO;
    inLandscapeRight = NO;
    inLandscapeLeft = NO;
}
else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
{
    isLandscapeMode = YES;
    inLandscapeRight = YES;
    inLandscapeLeft = NO;

} else if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    isLandscapeMode = YES;
    inLandscapeRight = NO;
    inLandscapeLeft = YES;
}

-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        isLandscapeMode = YES;
        inLandscapeLeft = YES;
        inLandscapeRight = NO;
        frameForProfile =   CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        isLandscapeMode = YES;
        inLandscapeLeft = NO;
        inLandscapeRight = YES;
        frameForProfile =   CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height);
    }
    else
    {
        isLandscapeMode = NO;
        inLandscapeLeft = NO;
        inLandscapeRight = NO;
    }

}
```

set BOOL according to your requirement

Answer (score 0):

From you screenshots I can see that your app is tab base. Few days earlier I faced same problem. I solved it. I asked a question almost same to your. Then after a few hours of reading I solved the problem. There is the link to my [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21747851/fixed-orientation-for-some-view-controllers).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of similar questions and answers on SO, but somehow none of them worked for me, as I needed to allow **only portrait mode on iPhone**, and **only landscape mode on iPad**, so sharing my solution:

1. Remove all methods related to device orientation (`shouldAutoRotate, supportedInterfaceOrientations, preferredInterfaceOrientations`, etc) as they might be conflicting with each other
2. In project settings enable all 4 modes: Portrait, Upside Down, Landscape left, Landscape Right
3. Chose a method for identifying device type (iPhone or iPad). I am using `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height which` is not ideal but suits my needs
4. Place the following in AppDelegate

   ```
   func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

       if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height < 760 { //iPhone
           UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarOrientation(.Portrait, animated: false);
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait;
       } else {
           UIApplication.sharedApplication().setStatusBarOrientation(.LandscapeLeft, animated: false);
           return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape;
       }
   }
   ```

Tested on Xcode 7.1.1 all iPhone and iPad simulators running iOS9.1